# WebdriverIO: Retrieving browser logging

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, logging, webdriver-io

According to [WebdriverIO-Dokumentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/chromium#getlogs) I can integrate the output of browser console logging into webdriverio-logging. My call is then `browser.getLogs('browser')`. However, only log messages issued with console.warn() are retrieved. All console.log() messages are ignored. How can I manage that and include all of console messages into my webriverio report?

Comment: Could you please check the `Level of logging verbosity` mentioned in the `wdio.conf.js` file ?. I guess by default it will be `logLevel: 'warn',`. Can you try changing it to `trace`, to get all the logs ?

Comment: No, that didn't help. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a recent version of Chrome and find that you only get warning and error messages in your logs, but you want INFO as well, add the following into your `wdio.conf.js`:

```
exports.config = {
  capabilities: [{
    ...
    "goog:loggingPrefs": {   // <-- Add this
      browser: "ALL",
    },
  }],
};
```

Comment: there is no such option in config types